# Show an error after submitting

Tags: php, phpbb

I want to show an error (in phpBB it's trigger_error) right after the user clicks submit.

I already have a function which checks if a link has been posted. Now I want to call it after the submit post button has been clicked.

Where do I find that? Probably in posting.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open posting.php.

find around line 631

```
    if ($submit || $preview || $refresh)
{
```

after add

```
  $post_data['your_url'] = "http://www.damienkeitel.com/index.php"; //remove the equals and url value if using in real post
  $your_url = $post_data['your_url'];
  $your_url_exists = (isset($your_url)) ? true : false;
  $your_url = preg_replace(array('#&\#46;#','#&\#58;#','/\[(.*?)\]/'), array('.',':',''), $your_url);

  if ($your_url_exists && http_file_exists($your_url) == true)
  {
    trigger_error('yeah, its reachable');
  }
  else if ($your_url_exists && http_file_exists($your_url) == false)
  {
    trigger_error('what da hell..');
  }
```

open functions_posting

find around line 19

```
/**
* Fill smiley templates (or just the variables) with smilies, either in a window or inline
*/
```

after add

```
function http_file_exists($url) 
{ 
  $f = @fopen($url,"r"); 
  if($f) 
  { 
    fclose($f); 
  return true; 
  } 
return false; 
}
```

Comment: Seems to be working the way I want,except that it always shows that the URL exists! :O

Comment: I have this working on my board. If I put www.78t8tjigsdfioua.com is returns the trigger_error('What da hell..');

Comment: ohh I see what's happening. it only checks if the domain exists. so if I already have http://google.com it shows that exists and if I have http://google.com/something it also shows that it exists. how to make it check the full URL ? including what comes after the domain.
Also,how do I let it continue submitting if the URL wasn't found ?

Comment: There are alot of of code changes to posting.php, includes/functions_posting.php, languages/en/common.php, styles/your_theme_name/posting_editor.html and viewtopic_body.html.
It is working on http://www.damienkeitel.com. Drop by my forum and we can discuss further.